# Problem on Regular Expression (PREG) for preg_match

Tags: php, regex

Possible cases: (pls ignore quote character'')

```
'#APPLE '
' PINEAPPLE'
' *LEMON '
' ORANGE… '
' * STRAWBERRY '
' PEAR '
' # BANANA'
' %KIWI '
```

I've try `%.[a-zA-Z]{2,}+%`
seem cannot solve this problem, any expertise can help to grep be

```
'APPLE'
'PINEAPPLE'
'LEMON'
'ORANGE'
'STRAWBERRY'
'PEAR'
'BANANA'
'KIWI'
```

Comment: Still show #Sharp, %percentage, @ at Characters

Comment: No, the expression is fine, it is likely your code is incorrect.  Show the code you are using to test.

Comment: Ah, you shouldn't get #, % or @ if you strictly specified [a-zA-z]{2,}+

Comment: Oh I added '%.[a-zA-Z]{2,}+%', 
it's fine if I remove dot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a website test tool for Perl regular expressions, e.g.

http://www.spaweditor.com/scripts/regex/index.php

Enter your expression:

```
%[a-zA-Z]{2,}+%
```

Enter your data:

```
'#APPLE ' ' PINEAPPLE' ' *LEMON ' ' ORANGE… ' ' * STRAWBERRY ' ' PEAR ' ' # BANANA' ' %KIWI '
```

And run the expression:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => APPLE
            [1] => PINEAPPLE
            [2] => LEMON
            [3] => ORANGE
            [4] => STRAWBERRY
            [5] => PEAR
            [6] => BANANA
            [7] => KIWI
        )

)
```

That uses the following function:

```
preg_match_all('%[a-zA-Z]{2,}+% ', '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of preg_match, use preg_match_all instead.

```
$pattern_test = "%[a-zA-Z]{2,}+%";
preg_match_all($pattern_test,$string,$matches);
print "<pre>"; var_dump($matches); print "</pre>";
```